# Algebra over an algebraically closed field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field and $R$ be a $k$-algebra. Prove that $R$ is a geometrically integral $k$-algebra if and only if $R$ is an integral $k$-algebra.

My attempt: ($\Rightarrow$) part is trivial, so we only have to prove ($\Leftarrow$) part.

Let $k'$ be an extension field of $k$ such that $k \neq k'$ . Since $k$ is algebraically closed, the only algebraic extension of $k$ is $k$ itself. Therefore, $k'$ must be transcendental over $k$, and so $k'$ must be infinite-dimensional as a $k$-vector space.

Now let $R$ be an integral $k$-algebra, and we have to prove that $R\otimes_k k'$ is an integral domain.

Here is where I stuck, Unlike an ordinary integral domain, we cannot guarantee that $a \otimes b = 0$ iff $a=0$ or $b=0$. How should I deduce that $R\otimes_k k'$ is an integral domain? Does anyone have ideas?

Any hints or advices are welcome!

Comment: i think you're suppose to show that $(a \otimes b)(c \otimes d) = 0$ implies $a \otimes b  =0$ or $c \otimes d = 0$ because the multiplication on $R\otimes_k k'$ is given by $(a \otimes b)(c \otimes d) = ac \otimes bd$; not sure if this is the right way to go about proving $R\otimes_k k'$ is a domain

Comment: also, you'd need to show $xy = 0$ implies $x=0$ or $y=0$ for all general tensors, not just simple tensors...